# Showing image and text in swipe actions in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am running my app on iOS 17 and have added swipe actions on list row. I wish to show the image of the action and text below it, but I noticed that only image gets displayed.

***Code:***

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                List {
                    Section {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Hello World").font(.body)
                            Spacer()
                           
                            Divider().frame(width: 3.0)
                                .overlay(Color.blue).padding(.trailing, -50.0).padding([.top, .bottom], -1.5)
                        }
                        .padding([.top, .bottom], 1.5)
                        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                            Button(role: .destructive) {
                                print("Deleting row")
                            } label: {
                                /// Note: Want to show Image and text below it.
                                VStack(spacing: 2.0) {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                    Text("Delete").font(.caption2)
                                }
                                
                                /// Note: Using label as well doesn't show both text and icon. It only shows the icon.
                                // Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                            }
                            
                            // TODO: Add more swipe action buttons
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I show image and text for swipe action?

[image]

Comment: I removed one of the questions. I will create another post for it. Leaving this for image and text in swipe action issue.

Comment: Great. The swipe actions *will* show both the text and image if there is enough room. Can you increase the height of the row so the text and image can be arranged vertically? I don't think you can force both of them to display when there is not enough space.

Comment: Hmm.. I see it now. I had to increase the height of 44px row to 70px row for text to show up which makes the entire row look weird because of extra top and bottom space. I wasn't even able resize height of the image even after adding .resizable to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to force an image to be shown together with a label is to build an image yourself that combines the two. This can be done by creating an `Image` with drawing instructions, see [`init(size:label:opaque:colorMode:renderer:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/init(size:label:opaque:colormode:renderer:))

For example:

```swift
private var deleteIcon: Image {
    Image(
        size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 40),
        label: Text("Delete")
    ) { ctx in
        ctx.draw(
            Image(systemName: "trash"),
            at: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 0),
            anchor: .top
        )
        ctx.draw(
            Text("Delete"),
            at: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 20),
            anchor: .top
        )
    }
}
```

You can then use this as the label for the swipe action:

```swift
Button(role: .destructive) {
    print("Deleting row")
} label: {
    deleteIcon
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

*EDIT* Following from your comment, longer labels could be addressed in various ways:

- The font can be made smaller by applying a `.font` modifier to the result:

```
deleteIcon
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .font(.caption)
```

However, this also impacts the size of the symbol. So it works better to set the font when rendering the label:

```swift
ctx.draw(
    Text("Check in").font(.caption),
    // ...
```

- The label can be made to truncate by drawing the text `in` a rectangle of fixed size:

```swift
ctx.draw(
    Text("A longer label"),
    in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 60, height: 20)
)
```

- If the rectangle for the text has sufficient height, labels will automatically wrap onto multiple lines, if necessary. Line alignment can be controlled by applying `.multilineTextAlignment` to the result:

```swift
advancedSettingsIcon
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

- As it turns out, other modifiers like `.lineLimit` and `.minimumScaleFactor` also work. So this opens the way for...

#### A more generic solution

Ideally, the generation of this type of composite icon should be able to handle longer labels automatically. This is possible by *resolving* the text and the image inside the function and then examining their sizes.

So here is a more general-purpose solution for generating a swipe icon. It includes the following logic:

- The font size for the label uses `.body` as default, but it is scaled automatically to fit.
- A line limit of 2 is applied, with a minimum scale factor of 0.7.
- If the label wraps to multiple lines, the symbol is made smaller.

I found that if the result has square proportions, it is able to fill the full height of the list row. So the function below generates an image of size 60x60. This gets scaled-to-fit, which probably means it gets shrunk a bit when actually used:

```swift
private func swipeIcon(label: String, symbolName: String) -> some View {
    let w: CGFloat = 60
    let h = w
    let size = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    let text = Text(LocalizedStringKey(label))
    let symbol = Image(systemName: symbolName)
    return Image(size: size, label: text) { ctx in
        let resolvedText = ctx.resolve(text)
        let textSize = resolvedText.measure(in: CGSize(width: w, height: h * 0.6))
        let resolvedSymbol = ctx.resolve(symbol)
        let symbolSize = resolvedSymbol.size
        let heightForSymbol: CGFloat = min(h * 0.35, (h * 0.9) - textSize.height)
        let widthForSymbol = (heightForSymbol / symbolSize.height) * symbolSize.width
        let xSymbol = (w - widthForSymbol) / 2
        let ySymbol = max(h * 0.05, heightForSymbol - (textSize.height * 0.6))
        let yText = ySymbol + heightForSymbol + max(0, ((h * 0.8) - heightForSymbol - textSize.height) / 2)
        let xText = (w - textSize.width) / 2
        ctx.draw(
            resolvedSymbol,
            in: CGRect(x: xSymbol, y: ySymbol, width: widthForSymbol, height: heightForSymbol)
        )
        ctx.draw(
            resolvedText,
            in: CGRect(x: xText, y: yText, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)
        )
    }
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .font(.body)
    .lineLimit(2)
    .lineSpacing(-2)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.7)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
}
```

Here's how it can be used:

```swift
Button(role: .destructive) {
    print("Deleting row")
} label: {
    swipeIcon(label: "Delete", symbolName: "trash")
}

Button(role: .none) {
    print("Advanced settings")
} label: {
    swipeIcon(label: "Advanced settings", symbolName: "gearshape")
}
.tint(.orange)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wowww.... very creative and innovative. I wouldn't have ever thought of this solution. I will try it out and will post an update.

Comment: Hope it helps! Answer updated with what may be a better way to draw the image - it seems to retain the default aspect ratio this way.

Comment: This is definitely an answer to my question. Not sure if I will be able to use it though. As listed in my question, I have more swipe actions and one of them has little bigger string "Check In". Increasing width of image takes care of it in English language, but if the string is longer in different language, then the text isn't wrapping or truncating. I tried setting truncate modifiers on "Text" element in the image, but that's not helping probably because it's an image.

Comment: Answer updated with a more generic solution that addresses the issue of longer labels

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! Really appreciate it. I will be working on this over the weekend and will leave an update here. Thanks again!

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! I did change the size of the image as per my needs, but works great overall. Thanks again!